# InstallShield authentication with pfx file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I generate a Setup with InstallShield. I have a .pfx file to authenticate de Signature but I do not know where and how Configure Installshield to read the .pfx. Anyone can tell me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

From [InstallationDeveloper blog](http://www.installationdeveloper.com)

[Using Code Signing Certificates in InstallShield, Part 1](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/286/using-code-signing-certificates-in-installshield-part-1/)

[Using Code Signing Certificates in InstallShield, Part 2](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/288/using-code-signing-certificates-in-installshield-part-2/)